# TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, undefined, typeerror

I would like to use Axios to delete a book from my list. I use the URL of my database + the id, but I can't find the way to specify the id in the URL and it stays undefined.

It looks like this :

```
export default class ListBooks extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { error: null, data: [] }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ data: res.data });
            })
            .catch(errorThrown => {
                this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
            })
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ number: event.target.value });
    }

        /**
        * Use to delete a book by the id.
        */
        handleDelete = () => {
            const id = this.data.number
            console.log(id);
            Axios.delete(process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH_BOOKS + id)
                .then(res => {
                     console.log(res);
                    console.log(res.data);
                    let cible = document.getElementById("book-admin" + id);
                    cible.remove();
                })
                .catch(errorThrown => {
                    this.setState({ error: errorThrown });
                })
        }

        render() {
            const { data } = this.state;

            return (
                <div>
                    <Container>
                        {data.map(books =>
                            <div key={books.number}>
                                <ListGroup>
                                    <ListGroup.Item disabled id={"book-admin" + data.number}>{books.name} {books.author}
                                    </ListGroup.Item>
                                </ListGroup>
                                <Button variant="outline-warning" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change" id={data.number} onClick={this.props.handleUpdate}>Modifier</Button>
                                <Button variant="outline-danger" size="sm" className="btn-admin-change" onClick={this.handleDelete}>Supprimer</Button>

                            </div>
                        )}
                    </Container>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Each time I push Delete button I have this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of undefined.

Can someone tell my what I did wrong?
Or what I need to had to have all informations needed?
Thank you

Comment: `const id = this.data.number` what is `data` ? did you mean `state`?

Comment: Also, there is no property named number in state at `constructor` if it should be there, better to define it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be:

`const id = this.state.data.number`

not

`const id = this.data.number`

A good tip to find this in future is to always trace back from what is undefined to find the last thing that is defined and work from there

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that and it is better, but I still have a problem : if I console.log on this.state.data, It prints the data perfectly. If I console.log on this.state.data.number, It prints undefined. I'm pretty sure it's something obvious I don't see ...

Comment: when you `console.log(this.state.data)` what does it show?

Comment: It shows an array of object with the datas from my database 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "5eaf4a8e72338f01199af40b", number: 1, name: "INFRA-", author: "Rebecca Topakian", format: "A4", …}
1: {_id: "5eaf4ad572338f01199af40c", number: 2, name: "PHOTOGRAPHIC FIELDS", author: "Joël Van Audenheage", format: "23 x 29 cm", …}
2: {_id: "5eaf4ba472338f01199af40e", number: 3, name: "SELFLESS", author: "Eugène Blove", format: "13 x 17 cm", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: yeh so coz it's an array of objects you need to do `this.state.data[0].number` where `[0]` is the index so you can change that to be any index you have in range. does that make sense?

Comment: I see yes. But it doesn't work anyway. If I console.log this.state.data[0].number It prints 1 on each one

Comment: yes but if you want to access the second one you need to change the index to be `this.state.data[1].number`

Comment: I think I'm completely lost in my thing

Comment: `.map(books, index)`  map takes a second argument of `index` so you can just pass that in like this `this.state.data[index].number` so it's scalable

Comment: but feel free to ask another question as I think it' veering off topic a bit. mark this answer as correct and upvote and if you ask a second question I would be more than happy to help answer that :)

Comment: Ok, I will do that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the number from `state` , you should do `this.state.number`

Now in your code, the undefined is caused by :

1-
`this.setState({ error: errorThrown })` is overriding the `state` object and removing the number field

Or

2-
You didn't initialize the state object correctly by not putting a number field

Or

3-
`this.state.number` has not been set or has been set to another undefined variable

The best thing to do is to print out `this.state` before every time you access it. So the last printed state before the undefined error will tell what are the fields present in the state.
If there is no number field then the error is caused by 1 or 2
If there is a number field but it has no value (undefined) then the error is caused by 3

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216690/discussion-on-answer-by-eeah-typeerror-cannot-read-property-number-of-undefin).

Answer (score 0):

There are no property data in constructor. Add data state at constructor.
And then replace `const id = this.data.number` with
`const id = this.state.data.number`